# PHP Date-Dependent Pagination

Tags: php, sql, html, pagination, paging

I have a site that stores a bunch of records in an sql database that i want to pull onto a page based on the date, which is stored as Y-m-d in sql.  But, I want to paginate the results based on day.

So for the index, i want to show all the results from the current day, for which i was going to use the php date() function as the WHERE in my QUERY.  But I'm hitting a snag on doing the pagination.  I want to have buttons at the bottom that go to the next page with a get, so index.php?page=2 would be tomorrow, but i cant figure out how to select "tomorrow" reliably from the database in my WHERE.

See, i was going to use date("U") to get the unix time in seconds of the first day on the first page and then just add 3600*$_GET['page'] for incrementing the date on the next pages, but that seems like a sloppy way to do it that might wind up messing me up.  Is this the only way or is there a better, more practical solution - thanks a lot guys I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If page 2 is tomorrow, then you're going to be looking at something like this:

```
$days_ahead = $page - 1;
$query = "... WHERE date = DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL $days_ahead DAY ...";
```

Note that this would work fine on the first page too (assuming $page gets defaulted to 1), it'd add 0 days to today's date.

Answer (score 0):

You experiment with strtotime:

```
$sqldate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 days'));
```

Comment: strtotime messes up, as i dont think thats how you implement it in the date function, i get 1969-12-31 no matter what the $page is

Comment: Hmm, it works for me. date takes two parameters: One formatting string and one optional timestamp. strtotime generates a time stamp from an almost arbitrary string. (Sometimes it feels like it's magic...)

Comment: the problem im having is embedding a variable into strtotime, for example strtotime("+'$page' days") isn't having it

Comment: You've got too many '''s there. The correct syntax would be:

    strtotime("+$page days")

(Or, if you want to be absolutely sure or use an array:

    strtotime("+{$page} days");

)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to fix it for my site

```
//'page' is a GET variable from url
if($page<=1) {
  $datemax = time();
  $datemin = time() - (1 * 2592000); //2592000 being seconds in a month
}
else{
  $datemax = time() - (($page - 1) * 2592000);
  $datemin = time() - ($page * 2592000);
}
```

And then obviously the query will look something like

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE dateposted >=$datemin AND dateposted <=$datemax
```